# Android Tabs and different Activities

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Let's say I'm building an app that will navigate via tabs. So every tab would be a form or an `Activity`.

How can I create a `TabHost` in one activity and then for every tab have a different one so I don't mix up my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly what you mean by "mixing up code". But navigating using tabs is easy to implement. There is one main Activity which lists all the tabhosts, and then they are called as and when they are clicked.
This is explained very well in this tutorial.
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask if there is any doubt.

Comment: By mixing code I mean this...If one tab is for let's say stopwatch and second tab is for weather forcast..those 2 are different sets of code and I dont want to write them in the same activity..so how can I have one "main" activity that controls and implements tabs and 2 activities for each tab specifically. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Thats what happens exactly. See the tutorial I have posted, it works exactly as you want, you just have to change the specific code in the activities. If this solves your query please upvote the answer.